# How to remove white color even tho the image is already transparent

Tags: texturing, transparency

For some reason, the white color won't disappear even tho the image is already transparent, can anyone help me solve the problem here?
[image]

Comment: add transparent in node

Comment: Please show the setup for material of the leaves; in Blender Internal it's enough to check Color and Alpha in *Influence* rollout of the texture settings and enable ZTransparency in material settings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

These are the basic settings to get the alpha work in Blender Internal: you must enanble transparency and set it to 0.0 in the material tab, and then let the image texture set it to matte only where colors are present. Also specular can be distracting.